# Fetching company updates from Linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api

As title says, I would like to fetch company updates from linked in to render them in a teaser on the website. However I'm not sure this is even possible with
LInkedin API as Oauth requires the visitor to login via Linkedin prompt which is, of course, undesirable in this scenario.
I have the company account that I would like to use for silent authorization and fetching.
My guts says it's not doable, but perhaps someone else knows better. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by making the API call on the back-end with your own account to pull the data you're trying to access.  The catch here will be to make sure that you properly implement a token refresh workflow on the back-end so that after 60 days when your authentication token expires, your system will automatically refresh the token (avoiding the need for any manual/user interaction).

Comment: All fully documented on the developer.linkedin.com website:  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#refresh